# Example of an Atomic Measure

Tags: measure-theory

***Definition:***

Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measurable space, an atom of the measure $\mu$ is a set $A \in\mathscr{A}$ with the property that
$\mu(A) > 0$ and for any $B\in \sigma (A)$ either $\mu(B) = 0$, or $\mu(A \setminus B) = 0$. If a measure has
atoms it is called atomic; in the opposite case, the measure is called non-atomic (or
atomeless). A measure is called purely atomic if $X$ can be written as the union of a
finite or countable number of atoms.

From the definition of atoms, we get the following corollary:

***Corollary:***

*Every purely atomic measure is an atomic measure.*

I am trying to find an example of an atomic measure that is not purely atomic, can anyone help me?

Comment: I think you can improve your question by including the relevant definitions.

Comment: Right, I already have, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The sum of the Dirac measure and the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R$ is atomic but not purely atomic, because $\{0\}$ is its only atom.

Answer (score 2):

E.g. take $X=[0,1] \cup \{2\} \subseteq \Bbb R$ (as a space), $\lambda$ the standard Lebesgue measure, and use the Borel measure on $X$ defined by: $$\mu(A) = \begin{cases} \lambda(A) & 2 \notin A\\
\lambda(A) + 1 & 2 \in A\\
\end{cases}$$

$\{2\}$ is an atom (of measure $1$) there are no more atoms, so $(X,\mu)$ is not purely atomic.